# Correct way to use Regexp in select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

In `MySQL` I want querying the information schema to find tables in a particular database.

I am using `Regexp` in the select statement like below.

```
select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='testing' and TABLE_NAME REGEXP 'test|test_10'
```

Output:

```
123_test
123_test_10
temp_test
temp_test_10
```

Here I am getting list of tables which end with `test` and `test_10` as indicated in the select statement.

I am getting the same result while using below.

```
select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='testing' and TABLE_NAME REGEXP 'test'
```

Output:

```
123_test
123_test_10
temp_test
temp_test_10
```

Using the second statement how can I get only list of tables that end with 'test`.

The expected output I want is

Expected Output:

```
123_test
```

Also I would like to exclude some tables in the list. Like exclude the tables that start with `temp` and end with `test`

Comment: show some sample input and the expected output (all exceptions included)

Comment: You are only looking for `test` not specific to the end of the string. The `test_10` is redundant (per provided regex). `TABLE_NAME REGEXP '(test|test_10)$'` would be ending with `test` or `test_10`.

Comment: Are these `test` and `temp` placeholders or just literal values? I mean, `LIKE` is the best option if these are literal substrings.

Comment: @Active_user . . . I think `temp_test` should also be returned.

Comment: Are you ever actually looking for `test_10`? it doesn't seem like you ever actually want that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't want `temp_test` in the output I specified this in the last line of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want table names then *end* in test, don't bother with `regexp`.  Use `like`:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' and TABLE_NAME LIKE '%test' ;
```

Why is `like` preferable?  First, it is standard SQL.  Second, under some circumstances (this isn't one of them) it can be optimized using indexes.

As for the regular express, just specify that the expression needs to be at the end of the name:

```
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' and TABLE_NAME REGEXP 'test$' ;
```

Comment: I am getting the partial result of my problem. How do I exclude the `temp_test` in the statement itself

Comment: @Active_user maybe add `and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'temp%'`